# How to make a dropdown list horizontally (values next to each other) in html/css

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, size

I have a question.

I am looking for a dropdown list which is showing values not only downwards but also next to each other. So the dropdown would fit better on my webpage.

The example on the left is how it looks right now, on the right the result id like to see.

Is this possible?

http://nl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=123ay2q&s=8#.U_NCKsKZP-Y

Answer (score 3):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/HP85j/500/)

css

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    columns: 2;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
}
```

Comment: Nice...just make sure the unprefixed property comes **after** the prefixed ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot 4dgaurav, but this one is a nav dropdown. Is it possible to make a dropdownlist with select and option tags, so it actually works and behaves like a <select>?

Comment: yes! you can do that, css column property actually divides the content into columns, so you can make a dropdown like select. You can provide with a jsfiddle and if there are any issues we can look into it.

Comment: This isn't the right way I am using I guess? http://jsfiddle.net/HP85j/501 I am sorry if im handeling jsfiddle wrong or asking the wrong things, really new into stack overflow. Anyway a lot of thanks for your help.

Comment: @4dgaurav can you please help me?